# Нет сводки в обозревателе объектов в VS17

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2017

Пользуюсь Visual Studio 2017. В VS есть такая классная вещь, как "сводка" в обозревателе объектов. Однако, у меня почему-то она не доступна если выбрана любая платформа .NetFramework, кроме 4.6 и 4.6.1. Подскажите пожалуйста, почему нет сводки для остальных платформ и что сделать, чтобы она появилась?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: 4]

Comment: Может у Вас .NET без полной справки?

Comment: А как это проверить?

Comment: Хороший вопрос, только что обнаружил, что у меня в студии вообще нет .NetFramework 4.6.2

Comment: Сводки под старые версии может не быть. Ее могли не сделать microsoft-овцовты. А про новую не знаю.

Comment: Я тоже так сначала подумал, под старые не делали, а под новую ещё не сделали. Однако, попросил своего знакомого посмотреть. Он посмотрел на .Net 4.5.2, у него есть, у меня нет. А у Вас есть сводка для .Net 4.5.2?

Comment: Нет только атрибуты

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Видимо, и не должно быть.

Если кто-то знает больше, поправьте пожалуйста.